# Perl regular expressions in the stringr package

Tags: regex, r, stringr

The `perl()` function is deprecated in the latest version of stringr in favor of `regex()`. However, I don't seem to be able to replicate the earlier behavior.

To capitalize the first letter of a vector of strings, this used to work:

```
name <- c("jim", "john", "bill")
str_replace(name, perl("^(.)"), "\\U\\1")
```

However, this no longer works:

```
str_replace(name, regex("^(.)"), "\\U\\1")
```

But using base R works:

```
gsub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", name, perl=TRUE)
```

Is there still a way to do this with the stringr package?

Comment: It now uses stringi to actually do the work.  Just use `gsub` directly if you want perl regex's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

stringr is now powered by [**stringi**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) instead which uses [**ICU**](http://userguide.icu-project.org/posix) regular expressions. If you want to implement **PCRE**, simply use `sub` directly while turning on `perl = TRUE` mode ...

```
sub('^(.)', '\\U\\1', name, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Jim"  "John" "Bill"
```

Comment: So there is no option whatsoever to use PCRE with stringr?

Comment: tha'ts a dealbreaker, I'd say